# Fail Matches when a Character Appears Six Times in a Row

Tags: .net, regex, regex-lookarounds, repeat

I want to validate a string of variable length - a VIN number. I want to ensure that it contains only alphanumeric characters and is between 9 and 15 digits in length. However, I also want to make sure that nowhere in the string is a sequence of six or more alphanumeric characters. I am using .NET's regex engine.

```
00THZY7564TTX --> should pass validation
X0000000TEVBV --> should fail validation
```

I've looked at a number of posts, but I can't seem to get it down 100%. Currently, I have

```
(?<!(0){5,}.*)(?!.*(0){5,}.*)[A-Za-z0-9]{1,}
```

but it seems to ignore the zeros in the string (in example #2 above, it matches the `0000TEVBV` portion).

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: `a sequence of six or more alphanumeric characters` Do you mean 6 or more of the SAME character (like six `A` chars)?

Comment: Yes, you assumed correctly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
^(?!.*(\d)\1{5})[A-Z0-9]{9,15}$
```

See the matches in **[the regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/bN9zK9/2)**.

- Allows 9 to 15 upper-case letters or digits with `[A-Z0-9]{9,15}`
- Does not allow one character (e.g. `A`) to be in a six-sequence, e.g. `AAAAAA`
- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- The `$` anchor asserts that we are at the end of the string

Comment: FYI made an assumption about what you meant by `a sequence of six or more alphanumeric characters`—let me know if you need any tweaks. :)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think that .net XSD regex doesn't use lookaheads. Is there any way to solve this without using lookarounds?

Comment: Mmm if it's .NET regex then lookaheads are definitely supported.

Comment: They are usually, but when using it inside an XSD document, it isn't working. And according to John's answer here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8b7aa4e3-7d84-4a0d-9974-cd1e0769dbc0/problem-validating-xml-against-xsd-with-regex-as-string-pattern?forum=regexp, it doesn't look like the lookaround feature is supported.

Comment: The only other option I can think of is to use an alternation to match what you **DON'T** want in order to neutralize it, and to mach **AND CAPTURE** what you **DO** want to Group 1. If the group is set, you have a match. `^(?:.*(\d)\1{5}.*|([A-Z0-9]{9,15}))$` For more on this technique read [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174/1078583). Whether your syntax allows you to examine Group 1, I don't know. :)